# Having a problem with Blazor Server application

Tags: c#, hash, scripting, blazor

I am trying to create a login page. It should accept user and password (which works like intended), but the password needs to be hashed which is the problem.

After starting the Blazor app, I get the "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property" error at the line which calls my method to hash the inputted password.

Here is my code:

```
@page "/"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@using System.Security.Cryptography
@using System.Text
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

<PageTitle>Login</PageTitle>

<div>

<h1>Welcome back!</h1><br />
<h1>Login here:</h1><br />

<EditForm Model=@login>
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Username">Username:</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value=@login.user class="form-control" id="Username" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Password">Password:</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value=@login.password class="form-control" id="Password" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Authenticate" class="btn btn-primary" />
</EditForm><br />

<p>User: @login.user</p>
<p>password: @login.hashedpassword</p>

</div>
@code
{

    public class Login
    {

        [Required]
        public string user = "";
        [Required]
        public string password = "";

        public static string HashString(string input)
        {
            using (SHA512 sha512Hash = SHA512.Create())
            {
                //From String to byte array
                byte[] source = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
                byte[] hashbytes = sha512Hash.ComputeHash(source);
                string hashedinput = BitConverter.ToString(hashbytes).Replace("-", String.Empty);
                return hashedinput;
            }    
        }
        public string hashedpassword = HashString(password);
    }
    Login login = new Login();
    
}
```

Comment: Are you referencing the `hashedpassword` variable from your razor page?

Comment: No I am not referencing it in the HTML markup.

Comment: Show me how you reference it please. B.t.w. a Razor page is HTML markup combined with special syntax that starts with an @-sign

Comment: I have added "public" before the variable and show it in a <p>-tag with "@login.hashedpassword"

Comment: Add your markup to the question please.

Comment: It looks like you have created a Login class inside your login page. That's like putting a class inside a class (so that you have do instantiate the inner login class ... which I guess you have done on the last line). Anyway, a razor component is a class already. Just put the code in the page without wrapping it in an inner Login class and see if that works. Your static function would probably better return a string, rather than set a field value in the razor page class.

Comment: Try this `string hashedpassword => HashString(password);`. I think a property referenced from `Razor` should have a getter. Like `string test { get; set; }`, And I agree with @topsail that you don't need the extra class.

Comment: Thank you! It was the missing getter all along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved by [Paul Sinnema](https://stackoverflow.com/users/561380/paul-sinnema)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72507608/having-a-problem-with-blazor-server-application/72508039#comment128085727_72507608)

> Try this `string hashedpassword => HashString(password);`. I think a property referenced from `Razor` should have a getter. Like `string test { get; set; }`, And I agree with @topsail that you don't need the extra class.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31947140)

Comment: @NickVu: Why do you say that? This looks like an answer to me.

Comment: Ah actually, I marked it as a commentary, so we don't need to make an answer for it, but seemingly the system generated my comment wrongly. Sorry for the misleading... @JeremyCaney

Comment: @NickVu: All good. There have been a few bugs in the past where the wrong auto-comment gets added. That said, it's perfectly okay to elevate a comment to an answer. (Though, as a matter of etiquette, it's preferred to give the contributor a chance to post their own answer first, and then post their answer as a Community Wiki. That's obviously not required, though.)